# Push notification does not work on all mobiles in Android app

Tags: android, push-notification

I have an app which is developed an Android in WinDev Mobile and is working properly in most of the mobiles.

But yesterday I got a complain from two users that the they is not getting any push notification.

One of the user who has complained is using Samsung Note 8 and the other one is using Panasonic phone.

On further investigation I observed that both these phones are not getting registered with Google's GCM.

The code I am using is:

```
//Register for Notification Here
NotifPushEnable(ActivatePushNotif,notifPushAllNotif)
NotifPushProcedure(ReceivePushNotif)
//=======================================
PROCEDURE ActivatePushNotif(bufIdentifier is Buffer, sError is string)

sRegURL is string

IF InternetConnected() = False THEN
RETURN
END

IF Length(bufIdentifier) > 0 THEN
    //Call remote Script to sinder the PhoneID in DB  
    sRegURL = "[XxXxX.XXX];
    sRegURL = StringBuild(sRegURL,bufIdentifier)

    HTTPRequest(sRegURL)
ELSE
    // Returns the error returned by the service
    Error("Registration error: ", sError)
END
```

Is there any setting which we can change on the phone to get Push Notification to work as expected?

TIA

Comment: Not the answer but one important thing for you to consider is not to use GCM anymore since it is being deprecated after april 11th... use FCM instead: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know that but I have another problem in case of FCM. That Problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369120/using-same-project-reciving-push-notification-from-google-fcm